# Ubuntu Login Loop on 17.10 Using GDM

Tags: gdm

After upgrading to 17.10 from 16.04 and uninstalling unity, I get the notorious login loop. I have tried removing the .Xauthority file, updating Nvidia drivers in tty, and doing lots of research online. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

do you have 2 GPU's by any chance ? I.e. 1 NVIDIA and 1 onboard ? Sometimes after upgrade or fresh driver install the settings for display will change, effectively running you into login loop

If that's the case please try the following:

From the terminal (i.e. Ctrl + Alt + F3)

```
prime-select intel
```

To switch to Nvidia card:

```
prime-select nvidia
```

To check which card is being used right now, run this command:

```
prime-select query
```